# sparse matrix showing 0 rows in dimension in process of using xgboost

Tags: r, dataset, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I am dealing with a dataset having 377 columns and 300 000 rows, but now i have taken almost all the NA values out of column and zero value columns too out of dataset and my sparse_matrix is showing dimensions of 0 * 176 columns. It is showing no of rows as zero.

It was working fine but i then deleted few least important variables and it is showing this

code used is this

```
sparse_matrix <-sparse.model.matrix((Responders)~.-1, data =train)




 dim(sparse_matrix)
[1]   0 173
> cxgb1<- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix, label = output_vector, max.depth = 4,
+                 eta = 0.8, nthread = 2, nround = 20,objective = "binary:logistic", eval_metric  = "auc")
Error in setinfo.xgb.DMatrix(dmat, names(p), p[[1]]) : 
  The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data
>
```

It is supressing  rows and showing them as 0

```
sparse_matrix
0 x 173 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 173 column names ‘NO_OF_Accs’, ‘HNW_CATEGORY’, ‘vintage’ ... ]]
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code in this process and find exactly where it's saying that nrow == 0?

Comment: It gt solved, loaded the R session again and it started working  again